# why scala Map does not implement unapply?

Tags: scala

I wrote the following use case in scala:

```
val wordShortcut = Map("volume" -> "vol", "report" -> "rpt", ...)

object WordShortcutCase {
  def unapply(key: String): Option[String] = wordShortcut.get(key)
}

val pluralR = "(.+)s".r

def encodeToken(token: String) = token match {
  case WordShortcutCase(short) => short
  case pluralR(singular) => singular
  case _ => token
}
```

if scala `Map` would implement `unapply`, I wouldn't need the extra `WordShortcutCase` object (i could use `case wordShortcut(short) => short` instead`). This seems a common pattern to me.

And so the question is why scala `Map` does not implement the `unapply` method?

Comment: I don't see how pattern matching on a `Map` is common practice. `Map.get` makes much more sense to me.

Comment: So what would be the return type for `unapply` of map?

Comment: It's 1. Rare occasion. 2. Semantically frustrating, it's strange that `key` is `mapping` of `value`, when you are usually see it opposite way

Comment: @Haspemulator `K => Option[V]` same as `get`, I guess

Comment: @Odomontois, hmm, I'd rather have it as `Seq[(K, V)]`. I understand not all maps have defined ordering, but such `unapply` at least offers something different from the `get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` doesn't implement `unapply` because there is no sensible implementation that has the same characteristics as other collections.

In particular, you seem to want `apply` and `unapply` to do basically the same thing.  But that's not how other collections work; they bind variables to contents and expect that the list is exhaustive (in the absence of a binding to "the rest"):

```
val xs = List("fish")
val ys = List("fish", "dish")
def iam(zs: List[String]) = zs match {
  case List(x) => println(s"I am a $x")
  case _       => println("Who am I??")
}
iam(xs)  // Prints 'I am a fish'
iam(ys)  // Prints 'Who am I??'
```

If `Map` were *not* a collection it would be free to implement `unapply` as another way to do an `apply`, more like regex does (though there, note that the key feature is being able to bind multiple variables to parts of the regex match).  But since it is, having a regex-like unapply would be highly confusing because of the difference from other collections; and because maps are unordered and unapplySeq is ordered, having the same unapply as other collections would also be confusing.  So it just doesn't have one.